# NonRecursive Makefile compilaion issue

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

After reading the Emile van Bergen Article on non recursive makefile, I am trying to move from recursive to non recursive, but seems like I am not getting it right.

Update: I finally got it right

The files are :

```
$ ls -R
.:
folder1  Makefile  test.c  topRules.mk

./folder1:
file.c  Rules.mk
```

---

### test.c

```
extern void sub_print();

void main()
{
    printf("Top Hello\r\n");
    sub_print();

}
```

---

### Makefile

```
TARGET  = test.exe
.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGET)

include topRules.mk
dir = folder1
include folder1/Rules.mk

$(TARGET): test.o $(OBJS_folder1)
        $(LINK)
```

---

### topRules.mk

```
COMPILE = $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
LINK = $(CC)  -o $@ $^ 

%.o:    %.c
    $(COMPILE)
```

---

### folder1/Rules.mk

```
sp := $(sp).x
dirstack_$(sp) := $(d)
d := $(dir)

OBJS_$(d) := $(d)/file.o
$(d): $(OBJS_$(d))
```

---

### folder1/file.c

```
void sub_print()
{
    printf("Hello Sub World\r\n");
}
```

Comment: You really have to state what is happening and what you expect to happen. Without that it's not really clear what you need.

Comment: I am just trying to compile 2 files which are in diff directories and am using a non recursive makefile approach.

Comment: That does not really clarify anything. To state what is happening means providing full exact transcript of a shell session. And describe specifically what's wrong with it. If you don't have anything to execute, you need to put more work into it and possibly ask about specific thing you don't know how to put into the makefile.

Comment: There seems to be a problem in my makefile, specifically in how the folder1 files are compiled and linked to top folder test.o. Which is not working as of now. Can you please look into Makefile topRules.mk folder1/Rules.mk what is it that I am missing.

Comment: The content of you topRules.mk appears to actually be the content of two files and a shell command, I assume everything before the shell command is meant to be part of the other .mk file?

Comment: @mSO: I can't tell what you are missing, because you didn't say what you want and didn't show us what it does and explain why it is wrong. A comment just won't cut it; you should edit the question. There is a lot missing there. (-1)

Comment: it was a cCp error, I have updated the question

Comment: @JanHudec, it seems pretty obvious what's wanted is to compile and link the two source files into an exectuable, and the results of running `make` are shown, what more do you want?

Comment: Ok, does the rules.mk in folder1 looks ok ? All am trying to do is generate .o of all .c. Which is also not happening

Comment: @mSO, no, Rules.mk looks completely broken, have you read my answer?

Comment: Yes I know, first time

Comment: Finally exact make error. -1 retracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The substitution generating list of sources from list of objects is wrong. It is not stripping the `.o` extension:

   ```
    SRC_$(d) := $(OBJS_$(d):%.o=%.c))
                             ^^
   ```

   Remove the variable altogether, you won't need it given the next point.
2. The `$(OBJS_$(d)): $((SRC_$(d))` rule is both superfluous and wrong:

   1. It is superfluous, because the `%.o: %.c` pattern rule applies and does the right thing.
   2. It is wrong, because it creates one rule to do all compilations, but you need to compile each source separately. I.e. when you have two files, it will expand to:

      ```
      foo.o bar.o : foo.c bar.c
      ```

      but you want two separate rules.

   Delete that rule altogether and don't add any other. The correct rule is there.

   Actually the error is due to the two rules interacting badly. The documentation says "if the rule got it's command from an implicit rule, `$<` will be first prerequisite added by the implicit rule". Since the implicit rule `%.o: %.c` comes first, it provides the command, but since the explicit rule provides the prerequisite, the implicit one adds none and `$<` expands to nothing. The explicit rule shouldn't be there. Than the implicit one will provide both the prerequisite and command and should work.
3. Since make without argument executes the first target in the file, you should either move the `$(TARGET): ...` rule before the include or should define a rule `all: $(TAREGT)` (no actions needed, but the rule should be marked `.phony`) near the beginning.

Note, that you don't actually need to be doing the substitution at all, because you don't need the rule where you use it either.

---

It sometimes happens that a directory needs special flags. In such case you still don't create special implicit rule for files in that directory, but you create special rule that sets variables locally for specific targets. The syntax would be:

```
$(OBJS_$(d)): %.o: %.c
    specific-command
```

or

```
$(OBJS_$(d)): %.o: CFLAGS=specific-cflags
```

the later still takes the recipe from the general implicit rule, but defines target-specific value of given variable. I suppose this is what was attempted with the invalid `$(OBJS_$(d)): $(SRC_$(d))` rule.

This is called [static pattern rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern) in GNU make documentation.

Comment: got it. Now I have very much simplified it. Getting the same error though. Updated the question

Comment: @mSO: No, you didn't. I'll make it explicit that I expect you to delete the incorrect rule altogether and without adding anything.

Comment: @mSO: I've extended explanation of point 2. Delete the `$(OBJS_$(d)): $((SRC_$(d))` rule from `folder1/Rules.mk` altogether and don't put anything new in there.

Comment: Got you point. Updated the makefile and rules.mk. Folder1 is getting compiled but test.o is not generated, thought .o rule should apply to it

Comment: @mSO: You didn't process my third point yet. You are running wrong target. Either ask for `target.exe` explicitly (run `make target.exe` instead of just `make`) or rearrange the targets so the _first_ target encountered when processing `Makefile` is one that builds `target.exe`.

Comment: Added it now. Is this the correct way, as this is not working either

Comment: @mSO: I said **FIRST**, not last! (the name does not matter, the order does)

Comment: Dear jan, can you plase fix it for me, aint getting it

Comment: @mSO: I've added mention of "static pattern rules", the thing you probably wanted to do with the incorrect rule.

Answer (score 0):

How are `$(sp)` and `$(d)` supposed to be set before `folder1/Rules.mk` is included?

You haven't set them, so they are empty.

The substitution `$(OBJS_$(d):%=%.c))` probably isn't doing what you want either.

Try adding some `$(info Current value of d is $(d))` lines to show what you've set your variables to.

Also, `main()` should return `int` not `void`.

Comment: My answer still applies, you don't set the variables you use, and your substitution is wrong

Comment: I just used the makefile and rules.mk from the article, there sp and d is not set in the top level makefile. I even downloaded OpenRadius 0.9.5 it isnt set there either. Btw with the current files I am getting this error make
cc  -o folder1/file.o -c 
cc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [folder1/file.o] Error 4